# How to limit the traversal times in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

When using Cypher, the following query actually will traverse all the possible paths as required.

```
START n=node(0)
MATCH (n)-[]-(p1:Person)
RETURN n
```

But what I want is: stop the traversal once one subgraph is found and return the result telling me that it matches. How to do that? Like giving a `LIMIT` over `MATCH`? But as far as I **know**, `LIMIT` only works on `RETURN` not `MATCH`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `LIMIT`, Neo4j will stop traversing the graph once it has found a match.

As Cypher is a declarative query language, the query optimizer will handle the `LIMIT` clause properly, i.e. it will consider the limit during pattern matching.

Let's design an experiment to prove this. The example data set:

```
CREATE
  (p1:Person),
  (p2:Person),
  (p3:Person),
  (p1)-[:KNOWS]->(p2),
  (p1)-[:KNOWS]->(p3),
  (p2)-[:KNOWS]->(p3)
```

The graph looks like this:

[image: Example graph]

First, remove the `START` clause from the query as it binds node `n` to a specific id, which is not something we want for this experiment. In general: `START` is already deprecated and you should avoid using it if possible.

Let's add a `LIMIT 1` constraint and use the `PROFILE` keyword to analyze the query plan:

```
PROFILE
MATCH (n)-[]-(p1:Person)
RETURN n
LIMIT 1
```

[image: Query plan with LIMIT 1]

Remove the `LIMIT` keyword and analyze the query plan again:

```
PROFILE
MATCH (n)-[]-(p1:Person)
RETURN n
```

[image: Query plan without LIMIT]

As you can see, the query plan with the `LIMIT 1` constraint only returns a single row from the **NodeByLabelScan** operation with 2 database hits, while the query plan without the constraint returns 3 rows with 4 database hits.

*Update:* as suggested by InverseFalcon's comment, you can also use the `EXISTS` function, which will result in a boolean value. Note however, that you still need `LIMIT 1` to get a single line in the results (and avoid unnecessary database hits).

```
PROFILE
MATCH (n)
RETURN EXISTS((n)-[]-(:Person))
LIMIT 1
```

[image]

Comment: You may also be interested in the EXISTS() function, if the only purpose of this match is to figure out if such a pattern or path exists or not.

Comment: Thanks @InverseFalcon, that's very insightful. I updated the answer with a solution using `EXISTS`. What is interesting though is that it seems that you should still to use `LIMIT 1`. Are there any more elegant ways with `EXISTS`?

Comment: It really depends on how it's used in the query. If you are matching to one particular node (like you are to node(0) in your original query) and want to know if a pattern exists for it, then use EXISTS() with that pattern and it will give you a true or false. If used when matching to many nodes (as in the query for this answer, where n matches to all nodes), it will calculate if that pattern EXISTS() for all rows. Remember that LIMIT applies to the entire result set, it's not on a per row basis.

Comment: Thanks for your answers @InverseFalcon ! `EXISTS()` does help. And since `START` is deprecated, we can use `MATCH (n:Person) WHERE id(n) = 12` in place of `START n=NODE(12)`. Using index to search over the graph is much faster, according to Neo4j.

Comment: Just be careful about using the internal node ids for lookup. As nodes are deleted, the same ids can be reused, which can throw off queries. Also, I'm not sure if node ids are retained as-is for database backups and restores. It's highly encouraged to use your own ID properties and values rather than the internal ones, and set uniqueness constraints on those properties for those node labels.